# Ошибка "The underlying provider failed on Open" при работе с БД

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

Работаю на WPF MVVM + EF6 + SQL Server

У меня на пк программа работает прекрасно, но при запуске на другом пк вылетает ошибка при запуске окно где выполняется действие с бд. Собственно сначала долго грузит, а потом вылетает ошибка:

---

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException" в
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения The underlying provider failed on Open

---

Код ViewModel который выполняеться при запуске:

```
AttestationDBEntities db;

public StructureDataBaseViewModel()
{
    db = new AttestationDBEntities();
    Departments = db.TDepartments.ToList();
}

private IEnumerable<TDepartment> departments;
public IEnumerable<TDepartment> Departments
{
    get { return departments; }
    set
    {
        departments = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Departments");
    }
}
```

Строка подключения

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AttestationDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.AttestationDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.AttestationDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\AttestationDB.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

Экземпляр MSSQLLocalDB у пользователя запущен

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open

Comment: ^ возможно, это то, что вам нужно